# Fetch requests in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am working in a small application for a class I am taking and I have an issue when I am using the fetch API

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      map: "",
      markers: [],
      Data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=ashkelon&v=20180729&client_id=MVLZGLPIAITJITM0OOFYER3C2ZRT5ERGGEWCC0T1YWV3HFZA&client_secret=1TBLTY0TSM1T320FEO3BJBGTMYVQPCMBOGO5GEBC0ZB1E5LK`
    )
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(
        function(data) {
          this.setState({ Data: data });
        }.bind(this)
      )
      .catch(function(e) {
        console.log("There is an issue with getting the information", e);
      });
  }
}

window.initMap = this.initMap;
loadJS("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDySeqpuOjQlckWJUMlbSW_w5CydOVTWJI&callback=initMap");
```

UPDATE : 
this will not provide with an error and the state is set, but what now happens is that my state is empty when i log the state in the initMap method.

At this point i see that the state is set for "that".
But if its set for "that" how can i use "this" state in the rest of my application i need this information to create markers on the google maps API

thanks in advance.

Comment: use `.bind(this);` after your fetch call.

Comment: What's the actual issue? What have you tried? Because setting `that = this` will not change what `this` is elsewhere.

Comment: @Nick the issue is that I cannot setState with the data I'm trying to fetch

Comment: You should ask a new question now that you see new behavior. Be sure to include a [mcve] when you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is undefined in your anonymous function. By assigning `const that = this`, you make the context from `componentDidMount()` available in all of the anonymous functions. Another solution is to `bind()` all functions with the correct context. For example

```
...
.then((function(data) {
    this.setState({Data: data.response.groups[0]})
    console.log(this.state.Data);
}).bind(this))
...
```

Now you can remove the declaration for `that`.

Comment: I think what you were going to show is that in this way inside your block you can replace `that` with `this`

Comment: @quirimmo My bad. I missed that change in the copy-paste. Should be fix now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Mike.G Did you also add the parentheses as shown in my code snippet?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, yes ill udpate the code for you to see

Comment: @Mike.G Also update with the errors and fix the formatting

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Updated

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really care about [IE11](https://caniuse.com/#search=arrow%20functions) support (and does not use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)) please consider using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (it's syntax sugar for functions that have the same `this` as the `this` around them)

*Note that [string literals](http://%20componentDidMount()%20%7B%20fetch(%60https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=ashkelon&v=20180729&client_id=MVLZGLPIAITJITM0OOFYER3C2ZRT5ERGGEWCC0T1YWV3HFZA&client_secret=1TBLTY0TSM1T320FEO3BJBGTMYVQPCMBOGO5GEBC0ZB1E5LK%60)%20.then(function(response)%20%7B%20%20%20%20return%20response.json()%20%20%7D)%20.then((function(data)%20%7B%20%20%20this.setState(%7BData:%20data.response.groups[0]%7D)%20%7D)%20.bind(this))%20.catch(function(e)%20%7B%20%20%20console.log('There%20is%20an%20issue%20with%20getting%20the%20information'%20,%20e);%20%7D)%20%20window.initMap%20=%20this.initMap%20loadJS('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDySeqpuOjQlckWJUMlbSW_w5CydOVTWJI&callback=initMap')) like you used, have similar compatibility table as [arrow functions](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) so you lose nothing and gain much cleaner code!*

The code with arrow functions looks like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
   /* ... */

   fetch(`URL`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({Data: data.response.groups[0]}))
      .catch(e => console.log('There is an issue with getting the information' , e))

   /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I previously used ES6 functions, i saw a post that showed a solution with ES5 so i changed to ES5 functions